# Imagick in PHP doesn't create images

Tags: php, imagick

I'm unable to use Imagick in PHP to create images. The functions are all present, but functions that fill the `Imagick` object have no effect.
Look at the following snippet:

```
<?php
    $img = new Imagick();
    $img->newImage(100, 80, new ImagickPixel("red"));
    var_dump($img);
?>
```

The output is:

```
object(Imagick)#1 (0) {
}
```

And the output of `var_dump($img->getSize())` is:

```
Array
(
    [columns] => 0
    [rows] => 0
)
```

So the point is that all those image creating functions I tested such as `newImage($x, $y, $color)`, `readImage($filename)` etc. have no effect at all, even though they claim to be successful by returning `true`. The error output seems to report no errors. It all works fine in GD, but I want to switch to Imagick now because GD lacks functionality.

So what is the matter with this? Did I forget to set an environment variable, call a preparing function, or did I just fully misunderstand how to use Imagick in PHP?

Comment: Did you install the Imagick module? It's not in the default PHP installation.

Comment: All the Imagick functions are defined, so it probably is installed.

Comment: Please read this: http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.installation.php

Comment: I have no root access to the server, so I recently asked the admin to install it. The functions were not defined before and now they are, so I believe he installed it correctly. I'm gonna ask him again though.

Comment: Try setting an image format $img->setImageFormat('png');

Comment: Before calling `newImage`: Error log says `Can not process empty Imagick object` and the script terminates.

After calling `newImage`: No effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using newPseudoImage works.

```
<?php

$img = new Imagick();
$img->newPseudoImage(100, 80, "xc:red");
$img->setImageFormat('png');

var_dump($img->getSize());

echo $img->getImageBlob();
```

I have no idea why new image doesn't work - I've opened an issue for it, as your code not working is non-intuitive https://github.com/mkoppanen/imagick/issues/148

Comment: Wow, `newPseudoImage` does indeed work. However, I actually want to load an image from a file, even though I expressed myself unclearly about that. Any Idea on how to do that?

Comment: This has become absolutely weird. Turns out all functions work now in my testing file, including `newImage`, but they do not in my actual file, even though they are in the same folder on the same machine. I don't get it.

Comment: Turns out that the image does load in both files, but `getSize` only works on pseudo images. I didn't notice that because I was not outputting the file (yet) but just trying to get its dimensions. Why does this not work? At least I can use GD as a workaround, even though it would be inefficient to load the image twice.